# string to integers from argv

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, argv

I've a program which is taking input from command-line and using them ahead. All this time the inputs were given separately after the invocation command eg `./a.out 1 2 3 4 5` and it was quite easy to use them (lets just sum them for the moment) -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        sum += std::atoi(argv[i]);
    }
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

but now the input format has changed to `./a.out "1 2 3 4 5"` and this method does not works correctly. I tried to take `"1 2 3 4 5"` to a string but then I cannot get the integers out of it. Nor can I think of any other solution at this moment. Is there any elegant method to take them out of argv without too much complexity?

Comment: (Why has the argument format changed? Just as part of a lesson?) Hint: you want to split the string on the space character to end up with an array of (string representations of) numbers that you can convert using `atoi`. Or, you can stream the input as one number at a time.

Comment: @struthersneil no lessons, I'm learning on my own and another program passes the following inputs as this to my program.

Comment: That's cool, and honestly self-led practice and inquiry is the only way to learn. I was just curious as to who controlled the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split the string. You can do this for example using string streams:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::istringstream iss(argv[i]);
        for (int n; iss >> n;) sum += n;
    }
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```